# Create a record with custom class and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # abstract
end

class Company < User

end

class Person < User

end
```

How can i create form with the selection of type ?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%# I would like to have a selector of classes ["Company","Person"] %>
    <%= f.input :type %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

In the controleur, what code should i write ?

```
@user = User.new(params[:user]) # Pb params[:user][:type] have no effect
```

Comment: do you mean to say you should have something like dropbox which lists all the entities of Company, Person?

Comment: are you using single table inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mass assign the type attribute. You can do it like this:

```
type = params[:user].delete :type
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.type = type
@user.save
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as concise as you could make it:

```
@@classmap = { :person => Person, :company => Company }
@@Classmap[params[:user].delete :type].new(params[:user])
```

DO NOT convert `params[:type]` directly to a class name.  That's a security hole waiting to be exploited.